# Como realizar pesquisa com intervalo entre uma e duas datas no Asp.Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Como realizar pesquisa com intervalo entre uma ou duas datas no Asp.Net Core 2.2.

Tenho o seguinte form abaixo contendo DataInicio e DataFinal

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "OrdensChegadas", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.TextBox("DataInicio", "", new { @class = "form-control", type = "date" })
            @Html.TextBox("DataFinal", "", new { @class = "form-control", type = "date" })
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
            </span>

        </div>
    }
```

Quando submeto o form a Controller pode receber os valores da DataInicio somente ou DataInicio e DataFinal

Em testes que realizei somente usando DataInicio não estou obtendo resultados, observando que também tentei com a condição abaixo:

```
var applicationDbContext = _context.OrdensChegadas.Include(o => o.GetVeiculo).Where(e => e.Data.ToShortDateString().Equals(DataInicio)).OrderBy(o => o.Ordem);
```

E assim também:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(DateTime? DataInicio, DateTime? DataFinal)
    {
        var applicationDbContext = _context.OrdensChegadas.Include(o => o.GetVeiculo).Where(e => e.Data == DataInicio).OrderBy(o => o.Ordem);
        return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando peguei casos assim era por que no banco de dados tinha salvo também hh:mm:ss, e da interface esses valores vinham zerados.
Para contornar você pode usar o .Date do DateTime pra eliminar essa possibilidade.
Só cuidado, que pelo menos uma de suas datas é nullable.

```
Where(e => e.Data.Date == DataInicio.Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Acontece que voce esta comparando um **DateTime** com **DateTime.ToShortDateString()**.

Para fazer comparação, é necessário normalizar os objetos que serão comparados.

Tente assim:

```
var applicationDbContext = _context.OrdensChegadas.Include(o => o.GetVeiculo).Where(e => e.Data.ToShortDateString().Equals(DataInicio.ToShortDateString())).OrderBy(o => o.Ordem);
```

Lembrando que o **DataInicio** deve ser um **DateTime** não nullable. Se for Nullable, coloque faça uma validação e após a validação, coloque um **.Value**, para acessar o valor da variavel nullable.